# JSON return object for jQuery .post is null (when it's not)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have a jQuery .post command that is calling a web service in my ASP.NET project.  That web service is running a stored proc and packaging the data into an object to be returned to the client.  When I look at the response via Firebug, everything is being sent back. However, when I try to access that response object it is null.  Why?

My jQuery:

```
$(".listingManagerEdit").live("click", function () {
    $.post("/WebServices/AoP.asmx/GetListingManagerByID",
        JSON.stringify({
            ListingMgrID: $(this).closest("li.listingMgrs").data("listingmgrid")
        }),
        function (data) {
            $(".billingName").val(data.Name);
            $(".billingOrgName").val(data.OrgName);
            $(".billingAddress1").val(data.Address1);
            $(".billingAddress2").val(data.Address2);
            $(".billingCity").val(data.City);
            $(".billingState option:selected").val(data.State);
            $(".billingZipCode").val(data.Zip);
            $(".billingPhone").val(data.Phone);
            $(".billingPhoneExt").val(data.PhoneExt);
            $(".billingFax").val(data.Fax);
            $(".billingFaxExt").val(data.FaxExt);
            $(".billingEMail").val(data.Email);
        }
    );
});
```

My web service:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public ListingManager GetListingManagerByID(int ListingMgrID)
{
    ListingManager LM = new ListingManager();
    DataTable dt = DataAccess.AoP.GetListingManagerByID(ListingMgrID);

    LM.Name = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    LM.OrgName = dt.Rows[0]["OrgName"].ToString();
    LM.Address1 = dt.Rows[0]["Address1"].ToString();
    LM.Address2 = dt.Rows[0]["Address2"].ToString();
    LM.City = dt.Rows[0]["City"].ToString();
    LM.State = dt.Rows[0]["State"].ToString();
    LM.Zip = dt.Rows[0]["Zip"].ToString();
    LM.Phone = Utilities.FormatPhoneNumber(dt.Rows[0]["Phone"].ToString());
    LM.PhoneExt = dt.Rows[0]["PhoneExt"].ToString();
    LM.Fax = Utilities.FormatPhoneNumber(dt.Rows[0]["Fax"].ToString());
    LM.FaxExt = dt.Rows[0]["FaxExt"].ToString();
    LM.Email = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();

    return LM;
}
```

The response (according to FireBug):

```
d:  {…}
__type  BusinessLogic.AoP+ListingManager
Name:   John Smith
OrgName:    
Address1:   123 Pine Street, 3rd Floor
Address2:   
City:   San Francisco
State:  CA
Zip:    94104
Phone:  (415) 123-4567
PhoneExt:   
Fax:    
FaxExt: 
Email:  me@me.org
```

In the success function of my .post call, "data" is null.

Comment: conosole.log your data object in your callback and see if the formatting isn't quite what you were expecting.

Comment: @Ryan - it just comes back null

Comment: And if you look at the response of the post in your web browser's developer console, is the data shown there?

Comment: @Ryan - if I have only console.log(data) in the callback and look in my browser console, it just says null.  If I just run the code as shown above (no console.log) it says: TypeError: data is null

Comment: I mean under the network tab in the console. You can view the actual packet and see if the response came back with a body.

Comment: @Ryan - under the network tab, selecting response, the response payload is:
{"d":{"__type":"BusinessLogic.AoP+ListingManager","Name":"Hi There","OrgName":"","Address1":"123 Pine Street, 3rd Floor","Address2":"","City":"San Francisco","State":"CA","Zip":"94104","Phone":"(415) 123-4567","PhoneExt":"","Fax":"","FaxExt":"","Email":"me@me.org"}}

Comment: data.Name won't work then, you'll need to do data.d.Name... but if your data object is null, there's another issue somewhere. Hmm.

Comment: Are you sure this data is correct : `ListingMgrID: $(this).closest("li.listingMgrs").data("listingmgrid")`? console.log it before the post.

Comment: @wazz Yup, the parameters passed back are OK and the web service is processing them and creating the object to pass back.  It seems the JSON representation of the object is getting to the browser but when I try to access it in the success callback it's null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to be passing back json but you're returning an object.

If you can use JSON.Net,

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LM);
// or serialize it in C#.
```

In the callback

```
function (data) {
    var o = JSON.parse(data);
    $(".billingName").val(data[0].Name);
    ...
```

Comment: That worked perfectly - thx!  In the interest of completeness, let me add that I had to change the return type of web service from an object to a string.  Also, I was able to access the return data as just "data" (as I originally wrote it).  I didn't have to use the [0] notation.